# Dropping item between listviews animation

Tags: c#, listview, windows-runtime, windows-store-apps, winrt-xaml

I have 2 `ListView` controls bound to 2 different `ObservableCollection<string>` like this:

```
<ListView x:Name="List1"
            Grid.Column="0"
            CanDragItems="True"
            CanReorderItems="True"
            AllowDrop="True"/>

<ListView x:Name="List2"
            Grid.Column="1"
            CanDragItems="True"
            CanReorderItems="True"
            AllowDrop="True"/>
```

When dragging and dropping items in their own respective lists I get the default animation like this:

[image]

But I cannot get the same animation when I hover over the second `ListView`. Why is that and how can I invoke the same animation in this case? I can handle what happens on drop but first I need to be able to invoke the same animation.

All current solution I have gone through does not have the animation or uses some other library/control to substitute for this. Any help or suggestion regarding this is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no default drop animation for a `ListView`. You'll need to create something yourself - or use a third party solution such as you report to have already found.

Comment: Like I showed on the screenshot above that its there and I am using a `ListView`. Do you mean no drop animation available when dropped on to another `ListView`? Because that is my problem.

Comment: @lbrahim the screen shot shows you starting to drag from a listview. there is no default animation for a listview being a drop target

Comment: Maybe I mixed up but what I meant through the screenshot was that when dragging the item and hovering it you get an animation but the same does not apply when I drag and hover an item of one list on to another list. I did not mean the drop animation. Sorry for the confusion.